# How can I boot Windows 10 from my HDD located in a caddy?

Tags: hard-drive, boot, laptop, ssd, operating-systems

**Intro**:
My laptop is DELL Inspiron 5720.
I had a single slot for HDD in my laptop with Windows 10 installed on it.

Then, I replaced my "old" HDD with a SSD. But instead of my ODD, I installed a caddy with that old HDD. Then, I installed Windows 10 on my SSD (primary disk) and it was working just fine (the HDD was also recognized as a storage device).

**3 months later SSD died...*
Now I want to **install back Windows 10 on my HDD** (which is **currently located in the caddy**, not in the original slot).
I run Windows Installation Media and installed it on my HDD (which is still sitting in the caddy). But laptop doesn't boot from the HDD.

*My question is:* ***What should I do to make my laptop boot (load the OS) from my HDD?***

1. Should I **take the HDD out of caddy** and **move it back** to
   the original slot? (It's kinda difficult, because I have to take
   apart almost the entire laptop to get to the caddy)
2. Is it the BIOS'a issue (maybe it can just use the caddy's HDD as a
   **storage device**, but not as a **boot drive**)?
3. Are there some **master/slave jumpers** on motherboard or HDD the
   will force the HDD to become the primary disk (I mean boot drive,
   not just for        storage)?

I hope that you can help me figure it out.

Comment: It should boot from the HDD on the caddy, the same way it would boot from a CD/DVD.It's a UEFI system and it expectes the EFI partition to be in the drive listed first. If the SSD is still there then it's probably the first boot device if no changes were made in the firmware (UEFI).

Comment: This shoiws a few settings that may be relevant for your case: https://www.dell.com/community/Laptops-General/Inspiron-17R-5720-won-t-boot-can-t-change-BIOS-settings-can-t/td-p/4125381

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia, Hi! Actually, I took out the SSD, so there is only HDD left inside laptop (within the caddy).

Comment: Have you changed anything in the uefi settings? You should be able to access it by pressing f2 (or something similar) at the boot screen. The laptop may disable caddy boot by default. Check out the boot settings/order and anything relevant for CD drives.